# Catching Content-Security-Policy exceptions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, cross-browser, content-security-policy

We have implemented CSP in our huuuge one-page web app. We keep getting errors time to time and some errors were result of improperly handled user-form inputs and some seem to originate from within user's browser.

Is there a way to harvest more data on client side when CSP exception happens? The server-side report misses vital data. We know source source URL, blocked URL, violated rule/directive... but that is not helpful as we don't know what was on the screen at the moment and if it is user's browser to blame.

**We need to know**

- what javscript module was being viewed at the time/what JS layer/detail
- **where was the original source/trigger to request that resource** - was it our fault of displaying uncleaned form-embedded HTML injected by some robot or was it user's infected browser inserting these malware links?

Is there some hook like window.onCSPException=func that we can hook on and run client-side analysis? We need to distinguish fast our problems from client browser's problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#Enabling_reporting:

> By default, violation reports aren't sent. To enable violation reporting, you need to specify the report-uri policy directive, providing at least one URI to which to deliver the reports:
>
> `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; report-uri http://reportcollector.example.com/collector.cgi`
>
> Then you need to set up your server to receive the reports; it can store or process them in whatever manner you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but we are already doing that but as I wrote "The server-side report misses vital data.".